# Excel keeps crashing if I change anything in the macro code

Tags: vba, excel, crash

I wondered if you could help me, I've written a macro that was working great and then excel started crashing whenever I do anything with it, I have reran excel with macros disabled and it still crashes when I change any of the code. I don't understand whats going on with it.
Since it's crashing when I even change the name of it, I can't see it being something wrong with the code itself. I have two macros in the worksheet, the second one still runs fine without crashing. But the first one does.

I managed to change the name and try and run it, it changes it back to Sub DefDec() - I also have no idea where this name came from. It highlights Sub DefDec in red and gives an error, expected identifier here.

Any ideas? I have added the code to the bottom and have already rebooted the system, many a time.

```
Private Sub DefDec()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim Previous() As Variant
Dim Current() As Variant
Dim Original() As Variant
Dim maxrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim p As Long
Dim f As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim o As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim Position() As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim strTemp As String
Dim N As Long
Dim w As Long
Dim NoExchanges As Integer
Dim pole As String
Dim h As Integer
Dim holidays As Integer

For h = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Worksheets(h).Unprotect Password:=""
Next h

k = 1
i = 3
maxrow = 3
Worksheets(1).Select
Do While Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "STAT.HOL'S (ST)"
maxrow = maxrow + 1
i = i + 1
Loop


N = maxrow - 4
ReDim Position(0 To maxrow)

Previous = Worksheets(1).Range("a4:a" & maxrow - 1).Value
ReDim Current(1 To UBound(Previous, 1))
ReDim Original(1 To UBound(Previous, 1))
For i = 1 To UBound(Previous, 1)
Current(i) = Previous(i, 1)
Original(i) = Current(i)
Next

'Sorting Feature - sorts the array until there are no more changes

Do
NoExchanges = True
For p = 1 To UBound(Current) - 1

    If Current(p) > Current(p + 1) Then
        NoExchanges = False
        pole = Current(p)
        Current(p) = Current(p + 1)
        Current(p + 1) = pole
    End If
Next p
Loop While Not (NoExchanges)



'Comparison of strings, makes an array with the change of position


For i = 1 To N
For j = 1 To N

    If Original(i) = Current(j) Then
        Position(k) = j
        k = k + 1
    End If

Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To N

Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Range(("C" & i), ("C" & N)).Value = Position(i)

Next i

' Changing the sheet data

For h = 1 To Worksheets.Count
If Worksheets(h).Name = "Calcs" Then
    holidays = h - 1
End If
Next h

Worksheets(1).Select
For i = 1 To N
Worksheets(1).Select
Cells(3 + i, 1).Select
Selection.Value = Current(i)
Next i

For h = 1 To holidays
Worksheets(h).Select
Range(Worksheets(h).Cells(4, 6), Worksheets(h).Cells(4 + N, 70)).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
For f = 1 To N
    For i = 1 To N
        If Position(i) = f Then
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range(Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Cells(i, 70)).Select
            Selection.Copy


            With Sheets(h)
                .Cells(f + 3, 6).PasteSpecial
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next f
Next h


For h = 1 To 2
If h = 1 Then
    o = 3
Else
    o = 32
End If

Worksheets("FLEXI").Select
Range(Cells(o, 3), Cells(o + N, 150)).Copy
Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

For f = 1 To N
    For i = 1 To N

        If Position(i) = f Then
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range(Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("Sort Sheet").Cells(i, 150)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            With Sheets("FLEXI")
                .Cells(o + f - 1, 3).PasteSpecial
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next f
Next h

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
skip_update = False
Worksheets("Sort Sheet").UsedRange.Clear
Worksheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Amy

Comment: Did you try to reboot your system?

Comment: bit sarcastic but yeah reboot

Comment: I have similar situation once a year. Rebooting Win helps and problem doesn't come up with the same macro right after rebooting.

Comment: Yes I have rebooted my system a good few times now, it has not fixed the problem. But I do have a clue, the Sub DefDec() at the start of my macro is now coming up red and it's treating everything as if it is not within a macro. I'll post the code.

Comment: Start your code in debug mode - F8 and then go through it line by line to see where the actual crash happens. Maybe that will give you a clue?

Comment: It will not run the code anymore as it doesnt see it as being a macro

Comment: You can't name your procedure `DefDec` as this is one of function described at help topic in `Deftype Statements`. So, it's forbidden to use all VBA key words as Module, Procedure or Variable name.

Comment: Yes I've just fixed it by chance, before it was crashing if I tried to change the name at all, I tried to change the name for SortingNamesMacro which I'm sure isnt a forbibben name and it still wouldn't take. And I never named it DefDec in the first place so I have no idea what was going on there. Still its working now, so it will forever be a mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now, managed to change the name suddenly for no reason.